# Object reference error in Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, lambda, expression-trees

I have the following code where I need to implement fulltext search on a list of objects. I managed to get this working in a console application. The problem is when I start using this in WebAPI application. I get a error message saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and the Source is `Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly`. 
It seems like some properties of the `Type T` are null and when it is accessed the error pops up. 
Can anyone tell me whether my understanding is correct or not and if its correct then can you also help me figuring out how to get rid of the null properties?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FullTextSearch<T>(this List<T> list, string searchKey)
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
            MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            var publicProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
            Expression orExpressions = null;
            foreach (MethodCallExpression callContainsMethod in 
                               from property in publicProperties
                               let myProperty =Expression.Property(parameter, property.Name)
                               select Expression.Call(myProperty, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(searchKey)))
            {
                if (orExpressions == null)
                {
                    orExpressions = callContainsMethod;
                }
                else
                {
                    orExpressions = Expression.Or(orExpressions, callContainsMethod);
                }
            }

            IQueryable<T> queryable = list.AsQueryable<T>();
            MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Where",
                new Type[] { queryable.ElementType },
                queryable.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpressions, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }));
            var results = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression).ToList();
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like a problem with whatever `T` is. I tried your code with a sample class and didn't have a problem. Can you post the class it's happening with?

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: If you use it in memory, you really don't need expression trees, you can use func with reflection. Then you can debug easily into your code, and see where the problem happens. In this case you only need expression trees, if you want to compile the lambda to a delegate, cache it, and use it to increase performance, but I think reflection should be fast enough too in most of the cases.

Comment: @Shlomo - Yes the problem is with T cause it has got lot of nullable members.

Comment: @MBoros - I thought of that and will try it out. Do you have a sample code snippet that I can refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys, I figured it out. Here is the code just in case someone needs it.

```
 public static List<T> FullTextSearch<T>(this List<T> list, string searchKey)
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
            MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            var publicProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
            Expression orExpressions = null;

            foreach (var callContainsMethod in from property in publicProperties
                                                                let myProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, property.Name)
                                                                let myExpression = Expression.Call(myProperty, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(searchKey))
                                                                let myNullExp = Expression.Call(typeof(string), (typeof(string).GetMethod("IsNullOrEmpty")).Name, null, myProperty)
                                                                let myNotExp = Expression.Not(myNullExp)
                                                                select new { myExpression, myNotExp })
            {
                var andAlso = Expression.AndAlso(callContainsMethod.myNotExp, callContainsMethod.myExpression);
                if (orExpressions == null)
                {
                    orExpressions = andAlso;
                }
                else
                {
                    orExpressions = Expression.Or(orExpressions, andAlso);
                }
            }

            IQueryable<T> queryable = list.AsQueryable<T>();
            MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Where",
                new Type[] { queryable.ElementType },
                queryable.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpressions, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }));
            var results = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression).ToList();
            return results;
        }
```

The only part that changed is the LINQ where I get two Expressions which contains one for "Contains" and one for "Not(IsNullOrEmpty)" expression andalso'ed .

Comment: Don't you want the conditional operator `Expression.OrElse()` instead of the bitwise operator `Expression.Or()`? Also you can simplify `whereCallExpression` with `queryable.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpressions, parameter).Compile())`.